# What is the difference between adding dependencies via Maven and via IDE?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

What is the difference between adding dependencies via IntelliJ IDEA (when I download the library to my computer and add it to the project via Project Structure -> Libraries) and via Maven (when I specify group id, artifact id and version in pom.xml)? And which of these ways is better?

Comment: What happens when you use intellij and someone else working on the same project (or simply wanting to build it) doesn't? Using maven solves this, for example.

Comment: Which one is better depends on the circumstances.

Comment: Also, I don't know whether IntelliJ does transitive dependencies resolution. I know that Maven does.

Comment: I don't think that an IDE will *resolve* dependencies at all.  The developer must do the resolution (i.e. working out what version of the dependency is needed, where to get it from, and downloading its JAR) by hand ... before adding them to the project's "Libraries" (or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using maven is better when we collaborate with others, so we keep the version in pom file and the build will be stable.

When we use IDE, we'll download the latest version of the dependency and it may lead to build issues.

I suggest to use Maven, or use Maven plugin which updates pom file.

Answer (score 3):

The main *functional* difference is that the Maven build tool takes care of:

1. finding where the particular version of the dependency you want is stored,
2. downloading the dependency JAR
3. adding the JAR to the build tool's local repo
4. telling the IDE's incremental compiler where the JAR is; i.e. via your IDE's Maven integration plugin

By contrast, if you add the dependencies using "Project Structure > Libraries" (or the equivalent in other IDEs, you have to do the above (1. 2. and 4.) yourself, by hand.

Other differences:

- Maven will take care of transitive dependencies.
- Maven can automatically deal with SNAPSHOT dependencies.
- If you do it via the IDE project structure, you are liable to either end up with dependent JARs in your source control repository ... or with other people having to repeat the manual process when they need build your software.
- If you do it via the IDE project structure, you have the problem that different IDEs do it differently.  This presents problems if different developers prefer to (or have to!) use different IDEs.

---

In short, it is better to use Maven or Gradle, or some other build tool that understands dependency resolution ... rather than doing the work manually and then configuring the project libraries using the IDE.

Especially if other programmers need to build your Java application.